# How to write a unit test for static variable?

Tags: java, junit

I have a class that has a static variable and a function that makes use of that variable. I need to write a unit test for shouldCreateNewToken() method.

```sql
public class Auth {
    private static Instant tokenExpiration = Instant.now();

    public boolean shouldCreateNewToken() {
        Instant currentTimestamp = Instant.now(); 
        Duration differenceInTime = Duration.between(currentTimestamp, tokenExpiration);

        if (currentTimestamp.compareTo(tokenExpiration) > 0 || differenceInTime.getSeconds() < 120) {
            return true;
        }   
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

First of all, it's almost impossible to unit test something properly when static variables are involved.
Changing the variable value or internal state have chances to leak in following tests, and it's much worse when several tests are ran in parallel (Surfire does run tests in parallel for example).

So the first thing to do is to refactor your code to don't use static variables.
You should for example use dependency injection, if you are using a framework with that feature such as Spring.

Secondly, to test time sensitive stuff as it looks to be the case here, you can use [clocks](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Clock.html).
As time is everywhere in applications, this isn't as easy to set up as it looks like, though.

Answer (score 1):

- I may not have enough context on how you're planning to use the Auth class, however, base on what I can see, your `shouldCreateNewToken` method will ALWAYS return true.

  Static variables are created before the `main` is executed. When your program/service is initialized, you'll already have a value for `tokenExpiration` (let's say 10), and when you're method is executed, it will always pick a value greater than the tokenExpiration (let's say 11,12,...)

  Here I shared a quick guide to understand that behavior: https://www.baeldung.com/java-static-variables-initialization
- About the mock question you have, there are 2 approaches which could be used:

  1. You could use [mockStatic](https://www.baeldung.com/mockito-mock-static-methods) from Mockito, or even PowerMockito has a similar approach (depending what you use/prefer), and mock the Instant object

     ```
     Instant instant = Instant.now();

     try (MockedStatic<Instant> mockedInstant = Mockito.mockStatic(Instant.class)) {
         mockedInstant.when(now()).thenReturn(instant);
         ...
     }
     ```
  2. The second approach is to pass the `tokenExpiration` instant as parameter of the Auth class' constructor, this way you 1) avoid the mocking, allowing you to pass the instant you want, and 2) allows you to create different Auth configurations base on different needs.

     ```
     class Auth {

         private final Instant tokenExpiration;

         public Auth(Instant tokenExpiration) {
             this.tokenExpiration = tokenExpiration;
         }

         ...

     }
     ```

Comment: `Auth.tokenExpiration` is not final, so it could be modified later, when a new token was issued. As you said: you miss some context … 

Comment: Agree, it could do that, but as it currently is written, it doesn't seem like it will change

Comment: Confessed – we all miss that context, but from the names of the class and the method we were shown, we can guess some of it.

Answer (score 1):

In the current form, you cannot test that code.

While you can still use Reflection to modify `Auth.tokenExpiration` for testing, you fail to set the local variable `currentTimestamp`.

Modify your code like this:

```java
public class Auth 
{
  private static Clock clock = Clock.systemUTC(); // NOT final!
  private static Instant tokenExpiration = Instant.now( clock );  // NOT final!

  public boolean shouldCreateNewToken() 
  {
    Instant currentTimestamp = Instant.now( clock ); 
    Duration differenceInTime = Duration.between( currentTimestamp, tokenExpiration );

    if( currentTimestamp.isAfter( tokenExpiration ) || differenceInTime.getSeconds() < 120) 
    {
      return true;
    }   
    return false;
  }
}
```

This allows you to manipulate the time: via reflection you can set the `Auth.tokenExpiration` to an arbitrary instant, then you modify `Auth.clock` before each call to `Auth.shouldCreateNewToken()`.

Have a look to [the Javadoc for Clock](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Clock.html#fixed(java.time.Instant,java.time.ZoneId)) for the details.

I assume you do not need help on how to use Reflection or on how to write the test itself?